# Does LayoutAnimation work with functional component

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I'm developing a react native app with the use of class component mostly. Class component gives me the ability to animate with only 4 lines of code:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
   UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
   LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
}
```

Now class component is not recommended any more by react rather than functional component. I wonder how do I implement the same animation as the code above in functional component?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import {LayoutAnimation, Platform, UIManager} from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

const setAnimation = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
            duration: 250,
            update: {
                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
                springDamping: 0.7,
            },
        });
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
            duration: 500,
            create: {
                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
                property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.scaleXY,
                springDamping: 0.7,
            },
        });
    };
```